# Prevent plotly selected traces from resetting when changing the variable to be plotted in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly, shinyapps

I am trying to make a shiny app, which consists of a sidebar panel and a plot. In the panel, I have radio buttons to select which ID should be plotted. I also have multiple variables which user can turn off and on using plotly legend.

I want the plot to be empty when app first opens. For that, I am using `visible = "legendonly"` in my plotly. But then, I want to keep the traces that user already activated (by clicking on them in the legend) when the ID is changed in the sidebar panel; however, since plotly get regenerated every time, again it uses `visible = "legendonly"` option and that causes the plot to reset.

Is there a way to keep the traces (only the ones that are already selected) when a different option gets selected in the sidebar panel?

See a reproducible example below; please note that I made this example to run locally. You need to load data and packages separately into your R session. Data can be found at the bottom of the question.

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)

### Read mdata into your R session
```

```r
# UI 

uix <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Data"),
  sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons('vars', 'ID', 
                 c("1", "2")),
    helpText('Select an ID.')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h4("Plot"),
    plotlyOutput("myPlot")
  )
)
)
```

```r
# SERVER 

serverx <- function(input, output) {
 
  #load("Data/mdata.RData") #comment out this part and load data locally
  
  # a large table, reative to input$show_vars
  output$uteTable = renderDataTable({
    ute[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]
  })
  
  output$myPlot = renderPlotly(
    {
      p <- plot_ly() %>% 
        layout(title = "Title", xaxis = list(tickformat = "%b %Y", title = "Date"),
               yaxis = list(title = "Y"))
      
      ## Add the IDs selected in input$vars
      for (item in input$vars) {
        mdata %>% 
          mutate(Date = make_date(Year, Month, 15)) %>% 
          filter(ID == item) -> foo
        
        p <- add_lines(p, data = foo, x = ~Date, y = ~Value, color = ~Variable, visible = "legendonly",
                       evaluate = TRUE)
        
        p <- p %>% layout(showlegend = TRUE,
                          legend = list(orientation = "v",   # show entries horizontally
                                        xanchor = "center",  # use center of legend as anchor
                                        x = 100, y=1))        
      }
      print(p)
    })
}
```

```
shinyApp(uix, serverx)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

#### Question: is it possible to keep the `Var1` trace when changing to `ID == 2`?

***Idea:*** I think it'd be possible if I could change the `visible = 'legendonly` to `TRUE` right after app deployment, so it only applies to the first example of the plot. Probably, I need to change `evaluate` to `FALSE` as well.

***Data:***

```
mdata <- structure(list(Year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), Month = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L), Variable = c("Var1", "Var1", "Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", 
"Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", "Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", 
"Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", "Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", 
"Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", "Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", 
"Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", "Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", 
"Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", "Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", 
"Var2", "Var2"), ID = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), Value = c(187.797761979167, 
6.34656438541666, 202.288468333333, 9.2249309375, 130.620451458333, 
4.61060465625, 169.033213020833, 7.5226940625, 290.015582677083, 
10.8697671666667, 178.527960520833, 7.6340359375, 234.53493728125, 
8.32400878125, 173.827054583333, 7.54521947916667, 164.359205635417, 
5.55496292708333, 151.75458625, 6.361610625, 190.124467760417, 
6.45046077083333, 191.377006770833, 8.04720916666667, 170.714612604167, 
5.98860073958333, 210.827157916667, 9.46311385416667, 145.784868927083, 
5.16647911458333, 159.9545675, 6.7466725, 147.442681895833, 5.43921594791667, 
153.057018958333, 6.39029208333333, 165.6476956875, 5.63139815625, 
197.179256875, 8.73210604166667, 148.1879651875, 5.58784840625, 
176.859451354167, 7.65670020833333, 186.215496677083, 7.12404453125, 
219.104379791667, 9.39468864583333)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -48L), groups = structure(list(
    Year = 2015L, .rows = list(1:48)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses `plotlyProxy` to replace the data for the existing plotly object (and traces) and therefore avoids re-rendering the plot. This approach is faster than re-rendering.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
```

```
# UI
uix <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Data"),
  sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons('myID', 'ID', 
                 c("1", "2")),
    helpText('Select an ID.')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h4("Plot"),
    plotlyOutput("myPlot")
  )
)
)
```

```
# SERVER
serverx <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$myPlot = renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly() %>% 
      layout(title = "Title", xaxis = list(tickformat = "%b %Y", title = "Date"),
             yaxis = list(title = "Y"))
    
    mdata %>% 
      mutate(Date = make_date(Year, Month, 15)) %>% 
      filter(ID == 1) -> IDData
    
    p <- add_lines(p, data = IDData, x = ~Date, y = ~Value, 
                                     color = ~Variable, visible = "legendonly")
    
    p <- p %>% layout(showlegend = TRUE,
                      legend = list(orientation = "v",   # show entries horizontally
                                    xanchor = "center",  # use center of legend as anchor
                                    x = 100, y=1))        
    p
  })
  
  
  myPlotProxy <- plotlyProxy("myPlot", session)
  
  observe({
    mdata %>%
      mutate(Date = make_date(Year, Month, 15)) %>%
      filter(ID == input$myID) -> IDData
    
    req(IDData)
    uniqueVars <- unique(IDData$Variable)
    
    for(i in seq_along(uniqueVars)){
      IDData %>% filter(Variable == uniqueVars[i]) -> VarData
      plotlyProxyInvoke(myPlotProxy, "restyle", list(x = list(VarData$Date), 
                                                     y = list(VarData$Value)), list(i-1))
    }
  })
  
}
```

```
shinyApp(uix, serverx)
```

[image: result]

For further information please also see chapter "17.3.1 Partial plotly updates" in the [plotly book](https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny.html), plotly's [function reference](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrestyle) and [this answer](https://community.plotly.com/t/what-is-the-most-performant-way-to-update-a-graph-with-new-data/639/6).

***Data:***

```
### Read mdata into your R session
mdata <- structure(list(Year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), Month = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L), Variable = c("Var1", "Var1", "Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", 
"Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", "Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", 
"Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", "Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", 
"Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", "Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", 
"Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", "Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", 
"Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", "Var2", "Var2", "Var1", "Var1", 
"Var2", "Var2"), ID = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), Value = c(187.797761979167, 
6.34656438541666, 202.288468333333, 9.2249309375, 130.620451458333, 
4.61060465625, 169.033213020833, 7.5226940625, 290.015582677083, 
10.8697671666667, 178.527960520833, 7.6340359375, 234.53493728125, 
8.32400878125, 173.827054583333, 7.54521947916667, 164.359205635417, 
5.55496292708333, 151.75458625, 6.361610625, 190.124467760417, 
6.45046077083333, 191.377006770833, 8.04720916666667, 170.714612604167, 
5.98860073958333, 210.827157916667, 9.46311385416667, 145.784868927083, 
5.16647911458333, 159.9545675, 6.7466725, 147.442681895833, 5.43921594791667, 
153.057018958333, 6.39029208333333, 165.6476956875, 5.63139815625, 
197.179256875, 8.73210604166667, 148.1879651875, 5.58784840625, 
176.859451354167, 7.65670020833333, 186.215496677083, 7.12404453125, 
219.104379791667, 9.39468864583333)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -48L), groups = structure(list(
    Year = 2015L, .rows = list(1:48)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

---

**Edit:**

The following is an alternative server function to update the trace data with a single `plotlyProxyInvoke` call (avoiding the for-loop):

```
serverx <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myPlot = renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly() %>% 
      layout(title = "Title", xaxis = list(tickformat = "%b %Y", title = "Date"),
             yaxis = list(title = "Y"))
    
    mdata %>% 
      mutate(Date = make_date(Year, Month, 15)) %>% 
      filter(ID == 1) -> IDData
    
    p <- add_lines(p, data = IDData, x = ~Date, y = ~Value, 
                   color = ~Variable, visible = "legendonly")
    
    p <- p %>% layout(showlegend = TRUE,
                      legend = list(orientation = "v",   # show entries horizontally
                                    xanchor = "center",  # use center of legend as anchor
                                    x = 100, y=1))        
    p
  })
  
  myPlotProxy <- plotlyProxy("myPlot", session)
  
  IDDataList <- split(mdata %>% mutate(Date = make_date(Year, Month, 15)), ~ ID + Variable)
  
  observe({
    selectedIDDataList <- setNames(lapply(list("Date", "Value"), function(i){
      unname(lapply(IDDataList[paste0(input$myID, ".Var", c(1L, 2L))], function(j){j[[i]]}))
    }), c("x", "y"))
    plotlyProxyInvoke(myPlotProxy, "restyle", selectedIDDataList, seq_along(selectedIDDataList)-1)
  })
}
```

Comment: @kraggle yes, the same can be done with a single `plotlyProxyInvoke` call as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75448129/9841389).

Comment: @kraggle if you have a new question post it as such - don't post it as an answer here. You can use `visible = FALSE` or `visible="legendonly"` to hide a trace.

Comment: The traces are numbered starting with 0 in the order they occur in the plot. For any further details: ask a separate question.

Comment: How would you retain the visibility without iterating over the new data (but data is changing)

Comment: I repeat: ask a separate question.

Comment: I tried to but they said it repeated this question. Which I think it may. What my solution would be is, capture the plot trace visibility values as reactive and feed that on the next invalidation. Thanks!

Comment: @kraggle regarding your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75476470/9841389): You fail to highlight the difference to this question. I guess your confusion is the result of a false assumption. When updating the x,y data for a trace via `plotlyProxyInvoke` the plot is *not* re-rendered (this is only the case if `renderPlotly` is invalidated) accordingly you don't need to retain the visibility values in the above scenario (they remain constant). The key is to avoid the re-rendering. However, your new question could be how to retain the trace visibility values despite re-rendering the plot.

Comment: Still I'd encourage you to use the above solution because updating an existing graph via `plotlyProxyInvoke` is faster than re-rendering the whole thing.

Comment: okay. It's not worth it in my scenario because the modularization of our plotly is very complex. Thanks though. Feel free to delete all the messages!

Comment: @kraggle if you need to retain the trace visibility values despite re-rendering I'd use plotly's `event_data` function and listen on "plotly_legendclick" and "plotly_legenddoubleclick" to update a `reactiveVal` which can be used to re-initialize the trace visibility after re-rendering the plot. Feel free to update your question accordingly and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

What I could think of was adding a check box to select the variables to be plotted instead of turning them off and on in the legend. Using this method, instead of using `visible = legendonly`, I leave the check box with no default values selected. Also, when user changes the ID, variables stay the same and therefore get plotted for the next ID. See below;

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)

### Read mdata into your R session
```

```
# UI 

uix <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Data"),
  sidebarPanel(
    radioButtons('vars', 'ID', 
                 c("1", "2")),
    checkboxGroupInput('varp', 'Variable',
                       c("Var1", "Var2")),
    helpText('Select an ID and Variables to be plotted.')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h4("Plot"),
    plotlyOutput("myPlot")
  )
)
)
```

```
# SERVER 

serverx <- function(input, output) {

  #load("Data/mdata.RData") #comment out this part and load data locally

  # a large table, reative to input$show_vars
  output$uteTable = renderDataTable({
    ute[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE]
  })

  output$myPlot = renderPlotly(
    {
      p <- plot_ly() %>% 
        layout(title = "Title", xaxis = list(tickformat = "%b %Y", title = "Date"),
               yaxis = list(title = "Y"))

      ## Add the IDs selected in input$vars
      for (item in input$vars) {
        mdata %>% 
          mutate(Date = make_date(Year, Month, 15)) %>% 
          filter(ID == item,
                 Variable %in% input$varp)-> foo

        p <- add_lines(p, data = foo, x = ~Date, y = ~Value, color = ~Variable, evaluate = TRUE)

        p <- p %>% layout(showlegend = TRUE,
                          legend = list(orientation = "v",   # show entries horizontally
                                        xanchor = "center",  # use center of legend as anchor
                                        x = 100, y=1))        
      }
      print(p)
    })
}
```

```
shinyApp(uix, serverx)
```

[image]

Comment: Is the question (self)-answered for you now?

Comment: @TonioLiebrand nah, as I explained in the bounty banner, I see this as a workaround.