# Retain some plotly traces when subsetting input data with sliderInput in shiny (R)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm trying to make an interactive plot that highlights clicks on a `plotly` plot in `shiny` and lets the user change the range of data displayed on the plot with `sliderInput`. I'm trying to retain already added traces if the range is changed after the user has already added clicks. Currently, it removes all existing traces because it completely renders the plot new each time.

I'm using `addTraces` instead of `restyle` the clicked marker because I also want to be able to delete traces and this was easier than restyling individual markers. I'm subsetting the data used to render the plot instead of just changing the x axis limits because I work with very long timeseries with tens of thousands of datapoints, and subsetting appears to greatly improve performance, which otherwise was very slow.

I tried adapting the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62355092/prevent-plotly-selected-traces-from-resetting-when-changing-the-variable-to-be-p), but because the use case is a little different and the data structure more complex, wasn't really able to. I'm still new to shiny, which probably is part of the problem.

I tried saving the corresponding values of each added trace into a reactive dataframe and add the traces upon `observeEvent`, but that didn't seem to work either.

```
#Sample Data
df<-data.frame(t=seq(as.POSIXct("2024-01-01 00:00:00", tz='UTC'),
                     as.POSIXct("2024-01-02 00:00:00", tz='UTC'), by="1 hour"),
               V1=sample(1:20,25, replace=T))
```

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

# UI

ui <-fluidPage(
  fluidRow(style = "padding: 15px;",
             actionButton("remove", "Delete last click", width='150px') 
  ),
  fluidRow(style = "padding: 0px;",
           plotlyOutput("plot"),
           div(style = "margin: auto; width: 90%",
               sliderInput("range", label = NULL, width="100%",
                           min = as.POSIXct(min(df$t), tz='UTC'), 
                           max = as.POSIXct(max(df$t), tz='UTC'), 
                           value = c(as.POSIXct(min(df$t), tz='UTC'), 
                                     as.POSIXct(max(df$t), tz='UTC')),
                           timeFormat="%F %T", timezone="+0000")
           ))
)
```

```
# SERVER

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    df[df$t>=input$range[1] & df$t <=input$range[2],] %>%
      plot_ly(x= ~t, y = ~V1, type='scatter', mode='line')%>%
      layout(showlegend=F) 
  })
  
  # highlight clicked point
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click"),{
    d <- req(event_data("plotly_click"))
    
    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("addTraces",list(x =c(d$x,d$x), y=c(d$y,d$y), type = 'scatter',
                                         marker=list(symbol='x', size=10, color='red')))
    })
  
  # remove last click
  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("deleteTraces", list(-1))
  })
}
```

```
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image: Interactive Plotly]

**Attempt with `observeEvent(input$range,{})`:** (doesn't work, i.e. does not add traces)

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  vals<-reactiveValues(
    d_click = data.frame()
  )
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    df[df$t>=input$range[1] & df$t <=input$range[2],] %>%
      plot_ly(x= ~t, y = ~V1, type='scatter', mode='line')%>%
      layout(showlegend=F)
  })
  
  #did my slider range change and I already have highlighted points?
  observeEvent(input$range,{
    if(dim(vals$d_click)[1]>0){
      plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
        plotlyProxyInvoke("addTraces",list(list(x=c(vals$d_click$x,vals$d_click$x), 
                                                y=c(vals$d_click$y,vals$d_click$y), 
                                                type = 'scatter',
                                                marker=list(symbol='x', size=10, color='red'))))
    }
  })
  
  # highlight clicked point
  observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click"),{
    d <- req(event_data("plotly_click"))
    
    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("addTraces",list(x =c(d$x,d$x), y=c(d$y,d$y), type = 'scatter',
                                         marker=list(symbol='x', size=10, color='red')))
    
      vals$d_click<-rbind(vals$d_click,d)
  })
  
  # remove last click
  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("deleteTraces", list(-1))
    
    vals$d_click <- vals$d_click[-nrow(vals$d_click),]
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the data like this:

```r
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    df %>%
      plot_ly(x= ~t, y = ~V1, type='scatter', mode='line')%>%
      layout(showlegend=F) 
  })

  Dat <- eventReactive(input$range, {
    df[df$t >= input$range[1] & df$t <= input$range[2], ]
  })
  
  observeEvent(Dat(), {
    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("restyle", list(x = list(Dat()$t), y = list(Dat()$V1)), 0)
  })
```

The `0` in `plotlyProxyInvoke` means that the restyling must be applied to trace 0 only.

However, if you added some points by clicking and if these points are outside the selected time range, then the time range of the plot will include these points. So you have to update the xaxis range too:

```r
  observeEvent(Dat(), {
    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("restyle", list(x = list(Dat()$t), y = list(Dat()$V1)), 0)
    plotlyProxy("plot", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("relayout", list(xaxis = list(range = input$range)))
  })
```

Comment: This works great, except that if I already have additional traces outside the subset timeframe, those continue to be shown too, so in that case the data is subset, but the x-axis isn't. I would need to hide any already existing traces outside that new timeframe, if that makes sense?

Comment: @Anke Maybe update the range too. Something like `plotlyProxyInvoke("restyle", list(layout = list(xaxis = list(range = range(Dat()$t)), yaxis = list(range = range(Dat()$V1)))`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work, or I possibly implemented it incorrectly

Comment: @Anke It's `relayout` actually: `plotlyProxyInvoke("relayout", list(xaxis = list(range = range(Dat()$t))))`.

Comment: Still not working on my end :( It's like it's simply ignoring the axis ```plotlyProxyInvoke("relayout")``` for some reason

Comment: @Anke I've just updated my answer to include this code. It works fine for me.